# how to read Step count in MI Band 4 using Flutter and flutter_blue?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app in flutter which can read the data (specifically the Step count) from MI 4 Band and pass it to my flutter app. so far I'm able to connect the device and able to show service lists. But, I'm Not Able to find the step count Data. How can I do so?

the full code I'm using....

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart' as flbs;
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter  BLE Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter BLE Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  flbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial bluetooth = flbs.FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance;
  flbs.BluetoothConnection bleConn;
  List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];

  List<BluetoothService> services = [];
  BluetoothService myImportantService;
  List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics = [];
  BluetoothCharacteristic myImportantCharacteristic;

  int counter = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bluetooth.requestEnable();
    discover();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void discover() async {
    List<ScanResult> res = await flutterBlue.startScan(
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 2),
      allowDuplicates: false,
      scanMode: ScanMode.balanced,
    );
    if ((await flutterBlue.connectedDevices).isNotEmpty) {
      await flutterBlue.connectedDevices.then(
        (value) => value.first.disconnect().then(
              (value) => Toast.show("BLE Disconnected", context),
            ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                devices.clear();
                Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (counter > 0) {
                      counter--;
                    } else {
                      counter = 10;
                      t.cancel();
                    }
                  });
                });

                List<ScanResult> res = await flutterBlue.startScan(
                  timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
                  allowDuplicates: false,
                  scanMode: ScanMode.balanced,
                );

                print(await flutterBlue.connectedDevices);

                res.forEach((element) {
                  print(element.device);
                  devices.add(element.device);
                });

                // try {
                //   await bluetooth.getBondedDevices().then((value) {
                //     setState(() {
                //       devices = value;
                //     });
                //   });
                // } on PlatformException {
                //   print("Can't connect");
                // }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Start Scannig Devices',
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "$counter",
            ),
            Text(
              'Available Devices:',
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: devices.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    // try {
                    //   if (bleConn == null) {
                    //     bleConn = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(
                    //         devices[index].address);
                    //     setState(() {});

                    //     if (bleConn.isConnected) {
                    //       var data = await bleConn.output.allSent;
                    //       // bleConn.input.forEach((element) {
                    //       //   print(element.first.toString());
                    //       // });
                    //       Toast.show(
                    //         'BLE Connected. \nData incoming: ${data.toString()}',
                    //         context,
                    //         duration: 10,
                    //       );
                    //       // Toast.show("BLE Connected", context);
                    //     }
                    //   } else {
                    //     bleConn.finish();
                    //     bleConn = null;
                    //     setState(() {});
                    //     Toast.show("BLE Disconnected", context, duration: 4);
                    //   }
                    // } on PlatformException {
                    //   Toast.show(
                    //       "Cannot connect due to: Platform Exception", context,
                    //       duration: 4);
                    // }
                    await devices[index].connect(autoConnect: false).then(
                          (value) => Toast.show("BLE Connected", context),
                        );

                    services = await devices[index].discoverServices();
                    for (BluetoothService s in services) {
                      //Would recommend to convert all to lowercase if comparing.
                      print(s.uuid);
                    }
                    print(await services[2].characteristics[0].read());
                    print(String.fromCharCodes(
                        await services[2].characteristics[0].read()));
                    // for (BluetoothService s in services) {
                    //   //Would recommend to convert all to lowercase if comparing.
                    //   print(s.uuid);
                    //   if (s.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() ==
                    //       "00002a53-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
                    //     myImportantService = s;
                    //     print(myImportantService.uuid);
                    //     characteristics = myImportantService.characteristics;
                    //     for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
                    //       //Would recommend to convert all to lowercase if comparing.
                    //       // if(c.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                    //       //   myImportantCharacteristic = c;
                    //       print(c);
                    //     }
                    //   }
                    // }
                  },
                  onLongPress: () async {
                    // try {

                    // } catch (e) {
                    //   Toast.show(
                    //       "Cannot Disconnect due to: ${e.toString()}", context);
                    // }
                    await devices[index].disconnect().then(
                          (value) => Toast.show("BLE Disconnected", context),
                        );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "${devices[index].name}",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Dependencies used in flutter

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
  flutter_bluetooth_serial: ^0.2.2
  flutter_reactive_ble: ^3.1.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
```

Comment: You should probably analyse the offered services and characteristics first using a generic scanner app such as nRF Connect. This might also help you: https://medium.com/@yogeshojha/i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-3-and-here-is-how-i-did-it-43d68c272391

Comment: I already did. But didn't find any matching service or characteristics

Comment: If you can't find a documentation for the BLE interface the MI band 4 uses or an existing project where someone did the work already there is no other way than just trying to figure it out yourself. You might have luck using a BLE sniffer to reproduce the communication between the band and the official app. This is a tedious task but it is the normal way if the device is not using a standard service or there is no documentation

Answer (score 0):

I did a project recently about this. And here is how I got the steps data.

1. Scan all the services the device is offering.
2. There is a service with id "0xfee0" (This is a company service. Mi doesn't use the "Physical Activity Monitor Service".
3. In this service, you'll find a characteristic with id "0x0007". This is the characteristic that gives the following data.
   a. Steps
   b. distance walked (meters)
   c. calories burnt
4. The data you'll be receiving from this characteristic will be a `List<int>` in bytes. The data can be converted into a readable format using below steps:

```dart
List<int> values = [byte(0), byte(1), byte(2), byte(3), byte(4), byte(5), byte(6), byte(7), byte(8), byte(9)];

// steps data - byte(1) and byte(2)
int steps = byte(1) + (byte(2) << 8);
debugPrint('steps: $steps');

// distance walked (meters) - byte(5) and byte(6)
int meters = byte(5) + (byte(6) << 8);
debugPrint('meters: $meters');

// calories burnt - byte(9)
debugPrint('calories: ${values[9]}');
```